# Flex VS Ajax / JQuery / Prototype or any otherjava script?

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache-flex

I am rebuilding one product website where client has 1000 of products which he wants user to filter as per his requirement without refreshing page. I am confused I should hire flex developer or Java script developer to deliver such project, looking at low bandwidth issue in India, which technology is more preferred? will using flex can effect search engine to crawl/read website content?
There are 30 odd filters for user to find his/her desire product.

Answer (score 0):

- Using Flex (Flash in general) would effect the SEO for sure; but Google doesn't execute JavaScript either, so product details might go unnoticed by search-bots if they aren't provided their own pages and linked to from a main page.
- The bandwidth won't be a big deal as the SWF needs to be downloaded only once (assuming it'll be cached). Even without cache, the section of folks who would go online for info on a product are likely to have a good bandwidth connection. I don't see much 56k dial up connections around as I used to in 2005.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for you to use Flex given your requirements. Javascript is easily fast enough in the browser to support 1000 rows. Filtering can be done with some relatively simple CSS.

Flex is useful for complicated apps that might desire some vector graphics, animations, movies, etc, but you'll find it very difficult to beat the speed of HTML/javascript when displaying tabular data.